# Question can become tagless

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, suggested-edits

Somehow [this suggested edit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/64336) cleared out the tags completely. This shouldn't be possible (and I can't reproduce it), but you can clearly see it happened from the image below, and from the [revision history](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/147067/revisions).

[image]

Comment: I saw this too. Very strange.  Couldn't manage to reproduce it though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per [this question on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212904/question-without-tags), there seems to have been an issue with tags on suggested edits that briefly got pushed out today; the code is apparently already fixed so that it won't happen again.